# create node ids with a multilinestring

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I've got to make a route with my multilinestring table "routebus", but I can't create the node ids... maybe the fact that it's a multilinestring is the problem, but I really don't know how to solve it. I created "source" and "target" fields and tried with this query:

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id('routebus', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

But it returns me an error:

```
ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
État SQL :22004
Contexte : PL/pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 36 at EXECUTE statement
```

I'm not really used to PostGIS and pgrouting, maybe un must convert multilinestring to linestring?

I have PostGreSQL 9.1.9 with PostGIS 2.0.1 installed

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PostGIS 2.0 and higher you can't use `ST_StartPoint` and `ST_EndPoint` anymore with Multilinestring geometries.

The `assign_vertex_id` function uses `ST_StartPoint` and `ST_EndPoint`, which means that you either have to to split your Multilinestrings into regular Linestring geometries, or you must use PostGIS 1.5.

But I think it's better you don't use Multilinestring geometries anyway, if you really have some. This may cause troubles with your network. In case you import SHP files with shp2pgsql and you don't specify the geometry type, it usually becomes Multilinestring even if your roads are all regular Linestrings. In that case it's easy to change the geometry type

Comment: ok, so I did like you said and reimport my shapefile in LINESTRING, and it worked! I didn't know that shapefiles does not differentiate multilinestring and linestring... thanks!